# Why 100 of ghost Oracle sessions are getting generated from JBoss7.1.0EAP to Oracle11g

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, oracle11g, jboss

We have recently upgraded our spring-mvc application in JBoss version from 4 to JBoss7.1.0.EAP. and also  Java6 to Java8 along with hibernate5.1 and also infrastructure from SunOS to RedHat Linux7.1. There was no upgradation for Oracle11g database. We have used standalone.xml  for connection pooling from JBoss. There is no code change in application just lift and shift.
On Production, we notice 100 of inactive Oracle sessions getting created and few sessions are running long time locking and blocking important tables, making the application slow.
We have used ojdbc14.jar in JBoss .

Is there any remedy or way to figure out why this is happening and how to resolve this.

Code for  in Standalone.xml

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="xxxxxxxxx" pool-name="xxxxxxxxx" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:Oracle:thin:xxxxxxxxxxx</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>500</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                           <user-name>xxxxxxx</user-name>
                           <password>xxxxxxxx</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                      <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                      <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                      <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                 </datasource>
```

Comment: You allow JBoss to create up to 500 connections - and I don't see any configuration that would close idle connections

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: `ojdbc14.jar` is intended to be used with Java **1.4** You should be using at least `ojdbc6.jar` or better `ojdbc7.jar` if you are using Java 8 with Oracle 11

Comment: is there any settings in standalone.xml to close inactive sessions. In codebase whenever we open connection, we made a point to close it. And there was no change in code during this migration

Comment: Yeah..will change that to ojdbc7.jar in the server.

Answer (score 0):

To configure idle timeout for connections you can add the element:

```
<idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
```

Afaik the default was changed from 15min to 30min in the more recent JBoss versions.

You can also consider to update the oracle driver to a more recent version (e.g. ojdbc7.jar).  See here https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-drivers-12c-downloads.html.

Comment: Yeah..will do that and let you know..Thnx